# How can i make a dictionary inside a class in c#?

Tags: c#

hello i need to make a dictionary that is different for every istance of class for example

```
 internal class items
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> items_property = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        private string property1;
        private string name_property1;
        private string property2;
        private string name_property2;
        private string property3;
        private string name_property3;


        public items(Dictionary<string, string> items_property, string property1, string name_property1, string property2, string name_property2, string property3, string name_property3)
        {
            this.items_property = items_property;
            this.property1 = property1;
            this.name_property1 = name_property1;
            this.property2 = property2;
            this.name_property2 = name_property2;
            this.property3 = property3;
            this.name_property3 = name_property3;

            items_property.Add(name_property1, property1);
            items_property.Add(name_property2, property2);
            items_property.Add(name_property3, property3);
            

        }
    }
```

i need a way to make something that create a key and a value for that key so the user can make multiple object and every object can have a Dictionary with different thing inside

example

obj car
key=speed value=100
key=price value=2000

obj dog
key=age value=5;
key=name value="doggo";

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean, and the last "example" isn't C# code at all.  Can you clarify, perhaps demonstrating the actual attempt you've made and what isn't working as expected in that attempt?

Comment: Please explain your **goal** here. What objective are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```cs
internal class Items
{
    Dictionary<string, string> ItemsProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Items(Dictionary<string, string> itemsProperty)
    {
        ItemsProperty = itemsProperty;
    }
}
```

If you create a variable of type `Items` called `itemsObj`, you could then access each property like `itemsObj.ItemsProperty["speed"]`, `itemsObj.ItemsProperty["age"]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If only those making the class needs to know about what is in the dictionary then you need a generic class

```
internal class items<T>
{

    Dictionary<string, T> items_property = new Dictionary<string, T>();
```